# Why can I use more licenses in M365 than purchased?

Tags: microsoft-office-365, licensing

In my Microsoft 365 admin center, I can see:

Assigned licenses: 3
Purchased licenses: 1

I checked the invoices and I am indeed charged for only one license.

How is that possible?

Comment: what kind of license is used?

Comment: Please go to the admin center, go to the Billing > [Licenses page](https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home#/licenses), find a list of **all the products that you have subscriptions for**. You can also see the total number of licenses for each product, how many licenses are assigned. For some subscriptions, you can assign licenses up to 20 users.